# How to use JSTL c:choose to change a form action

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a form action on my jsp page, which I would like the action to change depending on what the "user" being manipulated is.

```
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${user.user_username==username}">
            <form method="post" action="myinfo" class="form-horizontal">
        </c:when>   
        <c:otherwise>
            <form method="post" action="updated" class="form-horizontal">
        </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I have a submit button on the bottom of the page. Depending the user being manipulated, I would like to redirect the page to "myinfo" or "updated". However I keep getting an error saying that form has no end tag . I have it closed on the very bottom but I guess that's not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `<c:choose>` to set the action into a variable, then EL to use it in a form.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${user.user_username==username}">
    <c:set var="formAction" value="myinfo" />
  </c:when>   
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="formAction" value="updated" />
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<form method="post" action="${formAction}" class="form-horizontal">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: ah that's cool. Didn't know that was possible. Thanks! I'd +1 you, but I don't have enough points yet hehe